# Why is the length of smoothed data from filtfilt always double of the input?

Tags: filter-design, python, lowpass-filter

I am trying to filter the data I have using python with the code :

```
import scipy.signal as signal

#First, design the Buterworth filter
N = 3     # Filter order
Wn = 0.1  # Cutoff frequency
B, A = signal.butter(N, Wn, output='ba')

smooth_data = signal.filtfilt(B, A, np.ravel(rawdata))

plt.plot(rawdata, 'r-')
plt.plot(smooth_data, 'b-')
plt.show()
```

but the length of the smoothdata is always **double** the input ! so the time of the output signal will be doubled. which is not what I want.

is there any reason and solution for this ?

Comment: this is a typical syndrome of copy-pastaism: 1. why did you use a butterworth filter? That can be a very useful filter, but not as often as one would think in a digital environment 2. why did you do `filtfilt`, and did you read its documentation?

Comment: exactly for the same reason in this question : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120918/averaging-a-signal-to-remove-noise-with-python?rq=1

Comment: Shall you give a less general indication please ?

Comment: sure! `filtfilt` is a forward-backwards filtering algorithm, and it's rarely useful. However, many people just use it, because it sounds like "filter". Thus, I have severe doubts your code reflects what you *meant* to do. For the code you actually post, `len(smooth_data) == len(rawdata)`, so something else is amiss. Hence: you need to be sure that every line in your code reflects your intent. This hasn't be done by you so far.

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is exactly not happening ! which became my reason to post the question. I will post a screenshot of an example using this code

Comment: I'd much rather really understand *why* you're using a butterworth filter, and `filtfilt` than having a screenshot of something without reasoning. The screenshot tells us nothing but "something else works". Your code doesn't duplicate the length of `rawdata`, full stop. So, you'll have to look into what `rawdata` is and why you're doing what you're doing.